# Logging in AppleScriptObjC in Xcode

Tags: cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm writing code in AppleScript to glue an Obj-C Cocoa app to some other stuff.  I'm very unfamiliar with AppleScript on also learning Cocoa, so of course I have all kinds of bugs in my code to work out, and I need at least some logging.

However, output from the AppleScript 'log' command doesn't seem to end up in XCode's debugger console and calling NSLog doesn't seem to work.  Is there any way I can send output to the Debugger Console from within an AppleScriptObjC class method?

(suggestion: new applescriptobjc tag on this Q -- I can't create new tags yet)

Comment: You should show the code you are using; differently, it's not possible to know what you are doing wrong, if anything in your code needs to be changed.

Comment: I will post code if regulus6633's answer doesn't work.  I haven't tested it yet because right after I posted this question I discovered Scripting Bridge and immediately switched to that, since I'm much more comfortable in Objective-C than in AppleScript anyway.

Comment: That's why I don't use applescriptobjc myself. We have the scripting bridge and NSApplescript already, so I didn't see a need to learn another set of sytax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use applescriptobjc, so I'm not sure. However, I used to use Applescript Studio so maybe my experience there applies. I noticed that you can't have a log (or NSLog) statement inside of an application tell block of code. Basically if you do that then you are telling the application to log something and the application doesn't know the log command... so it wouldn't work. As such you have to get your log statements out of application tell blocks or use use **tell me to log "something"** in the tell block... which essentially tells applescript to do the logging.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely correct. I've put log statements in all sorts of places and never had a problem. If it is a problem, then the log command can just as easily be abstracted to a subroutine (e.g., like my answer to the OP's question) which does away with the current tell statement.

Comment: Went and tested it, this works for me where normal log statments don't.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal because this logs to the console and uses the shell, but this should at least get you something that works:

```
log_entry("Hello, World!")

on log_entry(theLine)
    do shell script "echo " & theLine & " >> ~/Library/Logs/AppleScript-events.log"
end log_entry
```